# JQUERY Radio button pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

Hi I am trying to implement jquery pop up with radio buttons in it.

Here is my jquery function:

```
$("#myPopup").ready(function() {

var popUpList = $('<div><input type="radio">A<br><input type="radio">B<br><input type="radio">C</div>');

showPopUpButton.click(function() {
    popUpList.dialog();
});
```

});

Respective html code on my jsp page:

```
<ul id="header_navigation">
    <li class="header_navigation_list">
        <a href="home" title="Home" class="header_navigation_link">Home</a>
        <span>|</span>
    </li>

    <li class="header_navigation_list">
        <div data-role="main" class="header_navigation_link">
            <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
            <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
                <p>This is a simple popup.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My query is I have given pop up code and id on jsp page but the pop link is not visible. Though the "Home" link is visible on webpage and is working. I have even included jquery libraries at the top of the jsp page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Can someone please advise me on What wrong I am doing while declaring my pop up on jsp page. TIA

Comment: Include `jquery.UI` lib.

Comment: Added, still it is not working. The popup link is not displayed.

Comment: Any errors in dev console?

Comment: @doutriforce it worked the showpop link is visible but further on clicking no popup is displayed. can you pls advise here.

Comment: I mean the browser's dev console.

Comment: @doutriforce it worked the showpop link is visible but further on clicking no popup is displayed. can you pls advise here.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If yes, then press F12 and click on console tab. Check for any javascript errors.

Comment: Yes using chrome, it shows console tab shows two errors:      Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                               next  error is                                                                                  
 Uncaught ReferenceError: showPopUpButton is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (webpage.commons.events.js:4867)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)

Comment: There you go, `showPopUpButton` is not defined. Hence, you can't call  `click` event on an undefined object.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, mate.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery popup will require stylesheet too
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">`

Find below working snippet matching your requirement:

```css
.radioText {
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul id="header_navigation">
    <li class="header_navigation_list">
      <a href="home" title="Home" class="header_navigation_link">Home</a>
      <span>|</span>
    </li>

    <li class="header_navigation_list">
      <div data-role="main" class="header_navigation_link">
        <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" style="min-width:100px;padding:10px;">


          <input type="radio" name="aehe" />
          <div class="radioText">A</div>


          <input type="radio" name="aehe" />
          <div class="radioText">B</div>

          <input type="radio" name="aehe" />
          <div class="radioText">C</div>


        </div>
      </div>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This could be a comment, since this won't fix all of his coding problems.

Comment: Thanks for advice @doutriforce but I don't have reputation to post the comment on someone others post.

Comment: Oh, i see. I've totally forgotten about that. Sorry.